# Save session Id in Localstorage vs Service

Tags: angular

I'm writing an application which needs authentication. Which one would be better?

1) make service to handle session id

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountContextService {

  model: imodel= {
    sessionId: ''
  };
}
```

and then use that session id in whole application

OR

2) save that session id in localstorage and read in every request (I need that I to pass in every get/post request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot if you want to persist the session id between browser's open, closes and page reloads, anyway LocalStorage is a valid option, you can use this module which works perfect with latest angular 2 version (2.4.6) [ng2-webstorage](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage)

You can create the service to handle the creation, retrieval and deletion of the session id from LocalStorage.